# Multisite - cannot remove specific sub-menu its parent menu. All sub-menus disappear

Tags: multisite, wp-admin, admin-menu

I am having issue with admin menu in multisite environment. I have a menu called **YRC Settings** which has two sub-menus, **YRC Global Settings** (first on the list) and **YRC Homepage Settings** (second in the list).

I want to hide the second item keeping the first one visible, so that when admin/user hovers on the parent menu i.e. YRC Settings, the first one (YRC Global Settings) flies out and the second item should not at all appear.

I used `remove_submenu_page( 'yrc_settings_page', 'yrc_home_settings_page' );`, but this hides both the sub menus, meaning when I hover over YRC Settings parent menu I don't see any sub menu flying out!

But when I use the same approach in single installation mode, this works. What should I do? According to the requirement I must make the first item visible.

`remove_submenu_page( 'yrc_settings_page', 'yrc_home_settings_page');` is used to hide the sub-menu which has the following URL:
`/wp-admin/admin.php?page=yrc_home_settings_page`

- **Menu with both sub-menus visible**

[image]

- **What I see when using `remove_submenu_page(...)`**

[image]

- **What I require:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was doing a mistake and glad that I found it! I was using `admin_menu` hook when it should be `admin_init`.

So the only change I had to make was:
`add_action('admin_init', 'restrict_admin_access_by_role', 999);`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27137866/what-wordpress-hook-fires-first-admin-init-or-admin-menu

Hope this would help somebody like me as well!